# options for storing relatively large amount of data

Tags: windows, cloud, cloud-computing

I'm currently doing a bit of research for a multinational company, as part of my thesis. Truth be told, I'm more of a software/programmer kind of guy, so I'm not quite in my element here. My question is, what options are there to store a medium-to-large amount of data? Think of 4.5-5TB right now, though this is likely to grow steadily over time. The locations of the people and buildings are not centralized, roughly 50% in one place, the remaining half spread over various countries across the globe. As far as I know, 2 entities are to be put on this medium. Web applications and a handful of programs, the latter could likely be offered as SaaS.

As far as I know, there are 3 options:

- buy and host your own servers
- buy your own servers, but let the hosting (maintenance,
  security, installing...) be outsourced
- Cloud (XaaS)

Does this sound correct, am I overlooking something or even making an error? Naturally I'm not looking for a 100% complete reply, which speficies absolutely everything on this topic, though something to help me on my way would be appreciated.

I'm fairly sure the current situation is as follows: All of the data is stored at a 3d party company or at the main building itself. Foreign employees get whatever they need through a remote link. Can't think of the specific word right now.

Comment: You need to figure out what your requirements are to the replication of the data. In particular you need to figure out if you need strong guarantees about data integrity in case of concurrent updates from different location. With the organization being distributed already you can host a replica in each of your largest locations, every location that has a replica will have fast read access. If you also perform backup copies from the local replica to a local backup storage in multiple locations, you have low risk of data loss.

Comment: Alright, then how do I go from there? I'm fairly sure the current situation is as follows: All of the data is stored at a 3d party company or at the main building itself. Foreign employees get whatever they need through a remote link. Can't think of the specifics right now.

Comment: It makes a significant difference what sort of access is needed to the data as well as how many people are updating the data and from where. The data access could be through a file system, an SQL database, a source repository/version control system. Replication would be done very differently for those three, and you haven't mentioned which it is. (And of course those three examples is by no means a complete list.)

Comment: Ah right right. Truth be told, I don't know all of the details myself. Any chance you happen to know of some sites/books to help me 'search' for the right solution and ask the right question to find it?

Comment: While I personally feel this is a great question, I feel it is too broad for our site. Voting to close, I don't want this to be a precedent for more people to ask these same kinds of questions.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what the data is and how often you're going to want to get it in or out of storage.  Something like YouTube with 5TB of video is going to have completely different requirements than 5TB of social security numbers and financial data.  Is it more important that the 5TB be highly available, or is it more important that the 5TB be very secure?  You mentioned a web site and an app that could be served as SAAS;  what are they written in? that might affect your answer as well.  (If the web site and app are LAMP, you might not want to store your 5TB in Microsoft SQL Server, simply because the people who know the different stacks are less likely to have cross-expertise, if you get what I'm saying.)

Assuming you're not going to go with a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (which you might, if the 5TB is just a pile of files you want to serve up on demand), for 5TB I'd suggest a dedicated server with dedicated storage and a pre-designed way to [shard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29) that data for future expansion.  Not knowing what the data is, though, I'm pretty much guessing.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Truth be told I don't know the specifics myself. The people in charge of that have been pretty busy lately. Pretty much all of the web applications are written in .NET. The final solution has to be a decent mix of multiple factors. Being highly available is a big factor, since the building are e.g. in America, Europe and Australia. Other than the web apps, there are 3 software packets, which are often used by the employees. Unfortunatly I don't know much more myself. What other questions do I have to ask?

Comment: If it's .NET you might already have licenses for versions of SQL that support [filestream](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which might be the way to go depending on the security requirements.  You might want to ask what format the data is in and whether your solution needs to comply with any regulations.  If they answer "It's our training videos and we don't care who sees 'em because they're all, 'Don't plug your thumb drive into your workstation!'" then maybe you should consider something more like the CDN.

Comment: Mmhm alright, thanks. I'm going to ask for some more information and come back when I know more.

Comment: Hey Katherine, congratulations on the 10k.